# Detect user selection for li

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items ("locals" array) which I show in a list

```
<ul class="list-group">
            <li ng-repeat="loc in locals" class="list-group-item"><a href="" data-id={{loc.ID}}>{{loc.location}}</a>
            </li>
 </ul>
```

I want the user to be able to select an item, and then to use this item in code.
What is the preferred way to do it.

Also I am creating the application for mobile, so I should be able to know that the user chose this item in mobile( and not just use mouseclick  for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of angular js ng-click event (on the li item where ng-repeat is and do something like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bFp6u/3/)

code snippet of controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.templateList = [{id:1, name: 'Template1'}, {id:2, name: 'Another Template'}]

    $scope.template = {};
    $scope.setValue = function(list) {
        $scope.template.template_id = list.id;
        $scope.template.template_name = list.name;
    }
}
```

Of HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
 <form ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="hidden" name="template_id" ng-model="template.template_id" />
    <input type="text" name="template_name" ng-model="template.template_name" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="list in templateList" ng-click="setValue(list)">{{list.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! It is  remarkable that ng-click receives the item as a parameter. Angular really makes life easier.

Comment: Thanks hope the answer is useful to you and acceptable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In html,

```
<ul class="list-group">
        <li ng-repeat="loc in locals" class="list-group-item">
          <a href="" data-id={{loc.ID}} ng-click="selectLoc(loc.location)">
            {{loc.location}}
          </a>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

In JS,

```
$scope.selectLoc = function(location){
  console.log(location);
     //Here you will get the selected location.
   var SomeVar = location;
 }
```

Hope this helps....